# Solving a Riccati equation - doesn't fit into any category I tried until now

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this ODE:

$$p = xp' - x(p^2 + x^2)$$

after dividing by $x \neq 0$ we get

$$ p' = \frac{p}{x} + p^2 + x^2 $$

Which I recognized as a Riccati equation, and also confirmed this on WolframAlpha.

However, here's the problem. We always dealt with three subtypes of the Riccati equation:

a) For any Riccati equation $y' = P(x)y^2 + Q(x)y + R(x)$, if P(x), Q(x) and R(x) are constants, then it is a separable equation

b) If $y' = Ay^2 + \frac{B}{x}y + \frac{C}{x^2}$, A,B,C are constants, we let $z=yx, z=z(x)$

c) If a particular solution $y_1$ is known, we let $y(x) = y_1(x) + \frac{1}{z(x)}$

However, my equation does not fall into any of the three categories I mentioned and I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Start with the change of variables $p=x q$, giving
$$q+xq'=q+x^2(1+q^2). $$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: so I managed to get that $q=\tan{(x+c)}$, and plug it in your equation to give me $p=x*\tan{(x+c)}$. I'm not sure whether I need to find the derivative of $p$ and then plug it into the original equation (because if I do I would only be left with a non-differential equation consisting of the variable $x$. Maybe I just need to plug the value $p$ into the original equation and then solve for $p'$?

Comment: Sorry, I made a haphazard mistake in calculation and also failed to realize that I just need to plug the solution in $p=xq$.

Answer (score 2):

$$p = xp' - x(p^2 + x^2)$$
$$xp' -p  = x(p^2 + x^2)$$
$$ \dfrac {xp' -p}{x^2}  = x\left(\dfrac {p^2}{x^2} + 1\right)$$
$$\left(\dfrac {p}{x} \right)' = x\left(\dfrac {p^2}{x^2} + 1\right)$$
This is a separable DE.
$$\arctan \left (\dfrac px \right)=\dfrac {x^2}{2}+C$$
$$p=x\tan \left (\dfrac {x^2}{2}+C\right)$$

Comment: Why does $$ \dfrac {xp' -p}{x^2} = \left(\dfrac {p}{x} \right)'$$?  It looks to me like you dropped a (p/x²) term there.

Comment: Try to differentiate $f/g$  here $f=p$ and $g=x$ @Brilliand

Comment: It's the rule. When you differentiate a quotient of functions such as $f/g$ you  get :  $$\dfrac  {f'g-fg'}{g^2}$$  @Brilliand  Take a look here for  the qotient rule https://web.iit.edu/sites/web/files/departments/academic-affairs/academic-resource-center/pdfs/product_quotient_rule.pdf

Comment: Oh, got it - I was wrong to treat x as a constant.

Comment: No problem  you're welcome @Brilliand